# How to make Oracle 11g Time-based SQL Injection Query including count(*) case count(*)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I try to make Time-based SQL Injection example Query for my Study

Query :

```sql
select case 
       when COUNT( * )>10
       then ( select count( * )
              from   all_users A,
                     all_users B,
                     all_users C,
                     all_users D,
                     all_users E,
                     all_users F
            )
       else 2
       end
from   col
where  tname='BBS';
```

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZcV7.png)

(`select count(*) from all_users A, all_users B, all_users C, all_users D, all_users E, all_users F`) : this is heavy query for oracle11g to make some delay

and if BBS table has more than 10 cols, I want to see some delay in my DB thank you for your HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because non-aggregated columns or identifiers(`the subquery with all_users dictionary views` in this case) cannot exist along with aggregated columns(`COUNT( * )>10` in this case) within a SELECT list of a query unless the non-aggregated ones are within GROUP BY list.

So, replace your query with an aggregated one :

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN COUNT(*)>10
       THEN MAX((SELECT COUNT( * )
                   FROM all_users A
                  CROSS JOIN all_users B
                  CROSS JOIN all_users C
                  CROSS JOIN all_users D
                  CROSS JOIN all_users E
                  CROSS JOIN all_users F))
       ELSE 2
       END AS result
 FROM col
WHERE tname = 'BBS'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c9e1d2036c4eadff683198c4f217eff9)</kbd>